# How to show a Panel with animation using RegisterStartupScript and jquery in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to show a panel from the code behind with an animation. The panel does show but with no animation, this is the line that is not working:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScriptBlock", "$(document).ready(function(){$('#" + pUserActions.ClientID + "').show(\"slow\" );});", true);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is postback fired from UpdatePanel?

Comment: What's the html for the panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that afer the PostBack the Panel (or div) is already visible, and `.show()` does not work if the element is already visible. Try this for example:

html:

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
<input type="button" value="Show" id="btnShow" />
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="btnHide" />
```

js:

```
$("#btnShow").on("click",function(){$("div").show("slow");});
$("#btnHide").on("click",function(){$("div").hide("slow");});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/VY9jt/

As you can tell, if you press the *Show* button when the div is visible nothing will happen. Try having the panel visible before calling the server side script and you will see what I mean. Note that the Visible property of the Panel control will not work, because this removes the element from the DOM altogether.